# How can I make the background color here to not move whan I hover the links?

Tags: html, css

This is A navigation bar with links that I made. I want that the black background will not move when hovering...

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 40%; 
}

li {float: left;}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

li a:hover {font-size: large;}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#Home"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#Articles"> Articles </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#About us"> About us </a> </li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: you should give the div with the background enough space, by hovering you increase the childrens width making it push eachother down

Comment: setting `height: 50px;` to the `ul` will do the trick when the browser width is enough to make the `40% width` of the `ul` fit all the children, but you may need to give the `ul` a bigger width when the screen gets smaller

Answer (score 5):

You  can use `transform:scale(X)`, it won't disturb the flow

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 40%; 
}

li {float: left;}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}

li a:hover {transform:scale(1.15);}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#Home"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#Articles"> Articles </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#About us"> About us </a> </li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>
</body>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms
>
> By modifying the coordinate space, CSS transforms change the shape and position of the affected content **without disrupting the normal document flow**. This guide provides an introduction to using transforms.

Comment: I agree dude, `transform: scale(2)` or something, is the better option.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you wanted to do something like this. Though I would suggest as @g-cyrelius mentioned, in other answer -- You should make use of `transform: scale(2)` or something, to avoid break of flow, in your code.

I tried to use your code `font-size: large`, but this is not the better option.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 80%; 
}

li {display: inline-block;text-align:center;position:relative;height: 50px;width: 30%;box-sizing: border-box;}

li a {
  color: white; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 16px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
 }

li a:hover {
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#Home"> Home </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#Articles"> Articles </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#About us"> About us </a> </li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```